# BORAR ULTIMOS CARACTERES DE UNA POSICION EN UNA LISTA

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy tratando dada una lista para cada posición borrar caracter por caracter hasta que encuentre un espacio, hice la prueba con un solo string y me sirvio pero cuando voy a hacerlo con una lista no me funciona esto es lo que hice

```
    cadena = 'buenos noches a todos espero la esténpasadomuybien'
    cnt = 0
    temp = len(cadena)
    while cadena[-1] != ' ':
        cadena = cadena[:temp - cnt]
        cnt +=1
    else:
        print(cadena)

    out
    buenos noches a todos espero la
```

Ahora cuando lo intento hacer con una lista me salen errores y no entiendo bien porque

```
    lista = ['Hola, buenos días','Hola mundo','Hace bastante calor el dia de hoy']
    lista2 = []
    cadena = ''
    cnt = 0
    temp = len(lista)
    for i in range(0,temp):
        cadena = lista[i]
        while cadena[-1] != ' ':
            cadena = cadena[:temp - cnt]
            cnt += 1
        else:
        lista2.append(cadena)
        cnt = 0
    lista2

    out
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

La idea que estaba pensando y que intento hacer es guardar las posiciones de la lista en la variable cadena, luego con el ciclo while mientras el ultimo caracter de cadena (que está en la posición i de la lista) sea diferente de un espacio en blanco va a ir eliminando con la ayuda del contador caracter por caracter y luego cuando ya encuentre el espacio en blanco lo agrega a otra lista, y luego sigue con la otra posición

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estás asignando sólo una vez **temp**, pero le asignas la longitud de la lista, no cómo tal la longitud original de la cadena que estás trabajando, y luego la llamas al crear la substring como si fuese la longitud original de la cadena, por eso se sale del rango.

Lo que pudieras hacer es agregar una tercera variable que almacene la longitud de la cadena que estás modificando dentro del ciclo for, y usarla cuando creas la substring

```
for i in range(0,temp):
    cadena = lista[i]
    original_len = len(cadena) # AQUÍ.
    while cadena[-1] != ' ':
        cadena = cadena[:original_len - cnt] # Y la usas aquí
        cnt += 1
   ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude solucionar mi problema

Comment: Genial, si consideras esta la respuesta deberías marcarla como tal para que la comunidad y futuros lectores puedan distinguirla fácilmente, de otra forma puedes autoresponderte y marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí dejo la solución con la que me ayudaron

```
    lista = ['Hola, buenos días','Hola mundo','Hace bastante calor el dia de hoy']
    lista2 = []
    cadena = ''
    cnt = 0
    temp = len(lista)
    for i in range(0,temp):
    cadena = lista[i]
    original_len = len(cadena) 
    while cadena[-1] != ' ':
        cadena = cadena[:original_len - cnt] # Y la usas aquí
        cnt += 1
    else:
        lista2.append(cadena)
        cnt = 0
    lista2

    out
    ['Hola, buenos ', 'Hola ', 'Hace bastante calor el dia de ']
```